# Manually Edited Word Files Created From HTML Documents Stored in Doc Libs Have Black Image Placeholders

Tags: document-library, html, word

I have an app in SharePoint that builds HTML markup containing an image (logo) inserted in the markup using base64-encoded and then creates a Word (doc, not docx) file in a SP document library

You can open up the file from the standard view of the doc lib and the Word file text and image are there.

Now open the Word file from the doc lib, do some manual editing of the file, save and close.

Re-open the Word file from the doc lib, and the image of the logo has an image placeholder area and the background is solid black.

Something happened between Word editor and SharePoint during the manual editing that it saved everything else in the Word file but not the image. Playing around with Word doesn't recover the image. File=>Inspect Document does not report anything. Continued editing actually causes the image part to disappear, with Word reporting that "header.htm" is missing

Why would Word lose data like that?

Comment: when you edit the doc file, does its extension changes to .docx?

Comment: Good question about whether the file name is changed by SP to affect the extension. No, the file name remains unchanged in the list Name column.

Comment: What type if image you using? jpg? png? I've tred the entire process and it seems to be working fine on my side.

Comment: This is a JPEG file. It is a logo that is read in by the script using FileReader API, then the data is rendered in a canvas element inside the script to get the image data, and that image data is inserted into HTML markup (as a string) which is then created as a Word file, all in JS code. This is saved to doc lib (using REST POST in JS code). When that file as doc lib item is opened in Word (desktop app), image clearly seen. After editing & saving back to SP item is when image disappears, placeholder w/ black bkgd seen.

Comment: If fixing SharePoint is a role you do, perhaps I can find a better way to illustrate the steps I am seeing or demo this to you, because I want the SP dev team to understand/explain this. Thanks